# Syntax error with try/except statement highlighting 'except'

Tags: python

I have a very simple try/except block to basically force the variable 'password' to be defined as an integer from user input.

It is likely a dumb question, but I have tried looking around and cannot find some solution.

```
    try:
        password = int(input('Password: '))

    except ValueError:
        print("Please do not type letters or symbols!!")

    while type(password) != 'int':
            try:
                password = int(input('Password '))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please do not type letters or symbols!!")

    print('Complete, we have your password.')
```

But, when I try run this python shell, it comes up with a Syntax Error, highlighting 'except'...

Comment: The extra new line after the `password = ...` line will cause this issue in the python shell. Try running it as a file and it should work.

Comment: Also count your parentheses and that's not how you check if a value is an integer.

Comment: Worth reading: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were couple of problems:

1. You have to use the comparision like this **type(password) is not int**:
2. **Define password variable beforehand**, otherwise it would not be recognized in your while statement

```
    password=""
    try:
        password = int(input('Bob should have issued you with your 4-digit numerical password, please enter it here: '))


    except ValueError:
        print("Please do not type letters or symbols!!")

    while type(password) is not int:
        try:
            password = int(input('Bob should have issued you with your 4-digit numerical password, please enter it here: '))

        except ValueError:
            print("Please do not type letters or symbols!!")

    print('Complete, we have your password.')
```

Comment: Sure, I'll work on that bit later. RIght now it won't even run because the Syntax Error popup. Is the try/except statement formatted correctly?

Comment: Copy and paste this code in an IDE (eg. Pycharm), execute the program. Please let me know if you still see the issue.

Comment: Beaut. Worked on both default and Pycharm. I think I should have had the varaible introduced above...? Anyway, thankyou for the help that has solved it. I am quite new to this so everything has been appreciated.

Comment: @Turdle you are welcome. If this post helped, please feel free to accept the solution and vote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new line after `password = ...`. Shell expects an except block not a new line. Also your parenthesis are not complete.

```
try:
    password = int(input('Bob should have issued you with your 4-digit numerical password, please enter it here: '))
except ValueError:
    print("Please do not type letters or symbols!!")
```

Comment: Please add your Error Stack Trace here.

Comment: It does not even open the run module, it just instantly says 'syntax error' in a popup window, and highlights the 'except'